# returning statement created by mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysqli_stmt_bind_param() to create an INSERT statement. For some reason I am getting an error. I used mysqli_error() to see the error message, but it's not especially useful.

Is there a way to just see what query is actually being executed?

the resulting error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,date,expdate,mintix,maxtix,contactname,contactemail,contactphone) VALUES (?' at line 1

Comment: Please show us your code. It's difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: In addition to what byronh commented, you should be able to store your query statement in a variable and then {log, echo, save} the query statement along with the error code.

Comment: @bdl I couldn't find a way to convert a prepared statement back to a string (I think what bigmac is asking for).

Comment: I think Brendan is right, but I added the code. Maybe I just can't see an extra comma or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepared statements created by mysqli_prepare() are *server-side* prepared statements.
When you execute such a prepared statement  only the statement id and the parameters are transferred, not some query string as if you would replace the placeholders by the actual parameters (on the client-side, i.e. your php script).
But you can see the result in the general log of the MySQL server, see [Prepared Statement Logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-prepared-statement-function-overview.html)

edit: in your case the preparation of the statement fails because `desc` is a reserved keyword.
For a list of keywords and how to use them as identifiers (if necessary) see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

```
$q = '
  INSERT INTO
    `event`
    (
      `cityid`, `name`, `desc`, `date`,
      `expdate`, `mintix`, `maxtix`,
      `contactname`, `contactemail`, `contactphone`
    )
  VALUES
    (
      ?,?,?,?,
      ?,?,?,
      ?,?,?
    )
';

if ( false===($stmt=mysqli_prepare($dblink, $q)) ) {
  /* 
    in production-code you might not want to reveal
    the error string to each and every user
    ...but for this example and for debugging purposes:
  */
  die('mysqli_prepare failed: '.htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($dblink)));
}

$rc = mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
  $stmt,
  "issssiisss",
  $city,$name,$desc,$date,
  $expdate,$mintix,$maxtix,
  $contactname,$contactemail,$contactphone
);
if ( false===$rc ) {
  die('mysqli_stmt_bind_param failed: '.htmlspecialchars(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
}


if ( false===mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ) {
  die('mysqli_stmt_execute failed: '.htmlspecialchars(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: Ahh, so *that's* the reason why neither mysql nor PDO support this properly. Thanks.

Comment: PDO can do both server-side and client-side (emulated) prepared statements (PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES). In the latter case it _would be_ possible to print a query string though it doesn't seem to be exposed.

Comment: I thought I've used desc as column name before, but I was wrong. I am surprised phpMyAdmin let me use it. I just tried changing it and phpMyAdmin displayed an error. It still managed to change it and now everything is working.

Thanks for all those ways to catch errors. That's really useful. Didn't realize all those were possible.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962986/how-to-echo-a-mysqli-prepared-statement), it is indeed impossible to get the final generated statement (which is horrible!), but maybe [mysqli_report](http://de.php.net/mysqli_report) as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219809/mysqli-prepare-statement-returning-false-but-why) can help you debug your query.