# Execute query inside a while loop.. MySQli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to update my current database from plain text passwords to hashes passwords using `crypt()`.. I'm trying to do this without users having to change their passwords (this is an instable approach) My code is like so:

```
$Query = $Database->prepare("SELECT ID,Username,Password FROM userlist");
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($ID,$Username,$Password);
   while ($Query->fetch()){
      $Hashed = $FrameWork->Hash_Password($Password);
       $Secondary_Query = $Database->prepare("UPDATE userlist SET Password=?, Salt=? WHERE ID=?");
       $Secondary_Query->bind_param('ssi', $Hashed['Password'],$Hashed['Salt'],$ID);
       $Secondary_Query->execute();
       $Secondary_Query->close();
   }
$Query->close();
```

I'm getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   C:\inetpub\www\AdminChangeTextPass.php on line 24

Now. I know my column names are 100% match aswell as my database names. I also know my variables are correctly set.

**Debugging**

Debugging:

```
$Query = $Database->prepare("SELECT ID,Username,Password FROM userlist");
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($ID,$Username,$Password);
   while ($Query->fetch()){
      echo $Password."<br>";
   }
$Query->close();
// Returns: 
//test
//test

Then: 
$Query = $Database->prepare("SELECT ID,Username,Password FROM userlist");
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($ID,$Username,$Password);
   while ($Query->fetch()){
      print_r($FrameWork->Hash_Password($Password));
   }
$Query->close();

/*
Returns: 
Array ( [Salt] => ÛûÂÒs8Q-h¸Ý>c"ÿò [Password] => Ûûj1QnM/Ui/16 )

Array ( [Salt] => ÛûÂÒs8Q-h¸Ý>c"ÿò [Password] => Ûûj1QnM/Ui/16 ) 

*/
```

**Database Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userlist` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Salt` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `userlist`
--

INSERT INTO `userlist` (`ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `Salt`) VALUES
(1, 'test', 'test', ''),
INSERT INTO `userlist` (`ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `Salt`) VALUES
(2, 'test', 'test', '');
```

---

Having my code look like this:

```
$Secondary_Query = $Database->prepare("UPDATE userlist SET Password=? WHERE ID=?");
$Query = $Database->prepare("SELECT ID,Username,Password FROM userlist LIMIT 1");
    var_dump($Secondary_Query);
#$Query->execute();
#$Query->bind_result($ID,$Username,$Password);
#   while ($Query->fetch()){
#       $Hashed = $FrameWork->Hash_Password($Password);
#       $Secondary_Query = $Database->prepare("UPDATE userlist SET Password=? WHERE ID=?");
#             $Secondary_Query->bind_param('ssi', $Hashed['Password'],$Hashed['Salt'],$ID);
#       $Secondary_Query->execute();
      # $Secondary_Query->close();
#   }
#$Query->close();
```

The `var_dump($Secondary_Query);` returns:

> ```
> object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2)
> ```
>
> ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000"
>   ["id"]=> int(1) }

And `var_dump($Query);` returns:

> object(mysqli_stmt)#4 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1)
>   ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0)
>   ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000"
>   ["id"]=> int(2) }

---

As I cannot submit an answer as of yet.. My working code is as followed:

```
$Query = $Database->prepare("SELECT ID,Username,Password FROM userlist");
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($ID,$Username,$Password);
$Query->store_result();
   while ($Query->fetch()){
       $Hashed = $FrameWork->Hash_Password($Password);
       $Secondary_Query = $Database->prepare("UPDATE userlist SET Password=?, Salt=? WHERE ID=?");
       $Secondary_Query->bind_param('ssi', $Hashed['Password'],$Hashed['Salt'],$ID);
       $Secondary_Query->execute();
       $Secondary_Query->close();
   }
$Query->close();
```

Comment: You are debugging the wrong thing.  The issue is that `$Secondary_Query` doesn't appear to be an object.  What does `print_r($Secondary_Query);` return after `$Secondary_Query = $Database->prepare("UPDATE userlist SET Password=?, Salt=? WHERE ID=?");`?

Comment: Also, the users should have different ID values.

Comment: @rtcherry Print_r($Secondary_Query); returns blank.. `Var_dump($Secondary_Query);` returns: `bool(false)`

Comment: @rtcherry Changed it. I manually written the insert query due to the inserts not being exported

Comment: Try enabling more error reporting by adding `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` to see if that helps narrow the problem (suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1220197/2355083)).

Comment: @rtcherry Warning: mysqli::prepare(): (HY000/2014): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: Hm, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now) question.  I think the answer for that one will apply here.

Comment: @rtcherry Submit the mysqli_report comment as an answer. I'll mark it, that really helped me solve my problem.

Comment: I am glad that helped.  Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Enabling more verbose error reporting was key in helping to debug the problem: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)`.

The following answer is from another SO question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614741/2355083).

You can't have two simultaneous queries because mysqli uses unbuffered queries by default (for prepared statements; it's the opposite for vanilla `mysql_query`). You can either fetch the first one into an array and loop through that, or tell mysqli to buffer the queries (using `$Query->store_result()`).

See [here](http://php.net/mysqli_query) for details.

Comment: This has helped me find the solution to my problem. I was not aware of the mysqli_report function. After adding this to my script, I was presented with a searchable error message. Hence finding the solution. This is included within my question.

Comment: I was having a similar problem, I was trying to run a query inside another query off a `while` statement. Adding `$query->store-result();` after the first `$query->execute();` fixed it by allowing it to run the 2nd query by storing the 1st results. At least that's what I think is happening, maybe somebody can verify that?