# mysqli prepared statement fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using a prepared statement that fails and I don't know why (no error is returned)
Here's my code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, temps, nom, classes FROM profs WHERE matiere = ? AND pass = 0");
if ( false===$stmt ) {
    die('prepare() failed: ('.$db->errno.')' . htmlspecialchars($db->error));
}
$rc = $stmt->bind_param("s", $mat);
if ( false===$rc ) {
    die('bind_param() failed: ('.$db->errno.')' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$rc = $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$rc ) {
    die('execute() failed: ('.$db->errno.')' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
```

This returns only: "prepare() failed: (0)"
Where's the problem?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @YourCommonSense: nothing returned..

Comment: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` will let you know what went wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT id, temps, nom, classes FROM profs WHERE matiere = ? AND pass = 0`

Is this query valid? Does the profs table exist, and do the columns (id, temps, nom, classes, matiere, pass) exist (and spelt correctly!)

Comment: infact, just `var_dump($db);` see what comes out?

Comment: Here's what I get from var_dump($db); :
`"object(mysqli)#1 (18) {\n [\"affected_rows\"]=>\n int(-1)\n [\"client_info\"]=>\n string(6) \"5.5.29\"\n [\"client_version\"]=>\n int(50529)\n [\"connect_errno\"]=>\n int(0)\n [\"connect_error\"]=>\n NULL\n [\"errno\"]=>\n int(0)\n [\"error\"]=>\n string(0) \"\"\n [\"field_count\"]=>\n int(6)\n [\"host_info\"]=>\n string(25) \"Localhost via UNIX socket\"\n [\"info\"]=>\n NULL\n [\"insert_id\"]=>\n int(0)\n [\"server_info\"]=>\n string(23) \"5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1\"\n [\"server_version\"]=>\n int(50531)\n`

Comment: Countinue:  `[\"stat\"]=>\n string(136) \"Uptime: 11142 Threads: 1 Questions: 848 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 612 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 152 Queries per second avg: 0.076\"\n [\"sqlstate\"]=>\n string(5) \"00000\"\n [\"protocol_version\"]=>\n int(10)\n [\"thread_id\"]=>\n int(141)\n [\"warning_count\"]=>\n int(0)\n}\n`

Comment: Not sure why you -1'd me, but nevermind. 

That indicates you are definitely connected, but I can't what is wrong if that is your exact code, and you put the var_dump($db) directly after the $stmt line...

Comment: I'm not the one who -1'd you.. :/
So there's no solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30617/discussion-between-ider-aghbal-and-farkie)

Comment: Hi, I just got the same issue trying to prepare an `INSERT` query ... For those who do not have any idea where to look at, [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219809/mysqli-prepare-statement-returning-false-but-why) is how I solved my problem !